# Zooming Google Calendar like browser zoom does but on a tab specific level

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a user script that will zoom https://calendar.google.com/ but on a per tab bases.

I don't want to use browser zoom because that changes the zoom for all tabs/windows open to the URL.

There are some extensions online but my security team won't let me use them.

I am able to use a user script with `document.body.style.zoom=1.5` to zoom the page but it messes up other content.

The best I can explain is with screenshots.

Here is the page without any browser or CSS zoom. Notice where the event info box is.

[image]

Here is the page when I do 200% `browser zoom`. Notice how the event info box is moved so you can still see all of it.

[image]

If I use `document.body.style.zoom = 2`, it does zoom, but now the event info box is not moved accordingly.

[image]

How can I get it to zoom like browser zoom but such that I can have each tab at a different zoom level?